# Downloading GraphQL Schema GitHub

Tags: graphql

How can I download the schema.json file from GitHub using schema:download command. Every time I run this command I get the following error:

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=https://api.github.com/graphql schema.json
  ✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✖ Saving schema to schema.json
    → ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 401
    Error: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 401
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're running into a rate limit issue

```sh
curl -v https://api.github.com/graphql
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
*   Trying 140.82.113.5...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x560df75c2f90)
* Connected to api.github.com (140.82.113.5) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Mar 25 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 30 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert, Inc.; CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x560df75c2f90)
> GET /graphql HTTP/2
> Host: api.github.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 403 
< date: Sun, 16 May 2021 04:24:14 GMT
< server: Varnish
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: deny
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, Deprecation, Sunset
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
< x-ratelimit-limit: 0
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
< x-ratelimit-reset: 1621142654
< x-ratelimit-resource: graphql
< x-ratelimit-used: 0
< content-length: 280
< x-github-request-id: 8408:67F9:583EDD:A2AEEF:60A09E6E
< 
{"message":"API rate limit exceeded for 162.216.16.149. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting"}
* Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact
```

[Read more](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations#rate-limit) about how to handle this

Answer (score 0):

First go to Github's **Settings** -> **Developer Settings** and select **Personal access tokens** and create a token. Make sure to include the scopes you want to fetch the data.

[image]

Then use any application that performs HTTP requests (Postman/Paw), add a `Authorization` header with the token you just created.

[image]

And execute the request. You'll get the schema JSON.

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/introduction-to-graphql#discovering-the-graphql-api)